# Jenkins try-catch the actual error instead of hudson.AbortException

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

how do I get the actual exception of a failed pipeline step/plugin?
I have the following pipeline code

```
try {
    checkout(
        scm: [ ... ]
    )
} catch (error) {
    echo error.getClass()
    echo error.getMessage()
}
```

which always results in

```
class hudson.AbortException
Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
```

But running without try/catch it would result in:

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://git.repo.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1003)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1245)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1309)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:97)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress --prune --depth=1 -- https://git.repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Unable to create '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/some_space/.git/shallow.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2734)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:623)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:158)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:151)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    ... 4 more
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to slave-lpdkwpci13vm
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1784)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1000)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:143)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1484.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:129)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy209.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1001)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1245)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1309)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:97)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:84)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        ... 4 more
```

so the real exception is:

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress --prune --depth=1 -- https://git.repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Unable to create '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/some_space/.git/shallow.lock': File exists.
```

**Is there a possibility to catch a `GitException` instead of `hudson.AbortException` or get the message from `stderr`.**

I already tried things like `error.getCause()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to here is [exception chaining](https://www.baeldung.com/java-chained-exceptions). I don't think you can catch a specific exception in the chain. You can walk the chain to see all the exceptions. To get the last exception, the `GitException`, you can use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28565320/3888850).

Comment: Looks promising. Will try it out. Thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to access the GitException?
I get null on the first `e.getCasue()` `e` is the abort exception

Answer (score 0):

Pipelines use regular Groovy, so you would use the normal Groovy approach for this:

```
try { 
   checkout() 
} catch(hudson.plugins.git.GitException e) { 
   // handle a GitException 
} catch(hudson.AbortException e) { 
   // handle an AbortException 
} finally {
   // cleanup
}
```

Comment: thansk for pointing that out. But as I tried to point out with `echo error.getClass()` the class is always `hudson.AbortException` even tho a `hudson.plugins.git.GitException` was thrown as shown in the logs

Comment: @Haagy I was a bit confused by your question so I tried to answer the part in bold ("Is there a possibility to catch a GitException instead of hudson.AbortException...").  But it looks like the other answer better addressed your actual issue so hopefully you were able to get this figured out :)